# Improve quality panel print

Tags: c#, forms, printing, panel

I have a problem printing high quality images, I'm making a panel that contains bar codes and some information about a product, so the quality of the image has to be high quality. Im using the example provided by msdn, here is my code.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
                 public static extern long BitBlt (IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest,int nWidth,nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
                 private Bitmap memoryImage;
                 private void CaptureScreen()
      {
                 Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

                 memoryImage = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, mygraphics);
                 Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
                 IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();
                 IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
                 BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0,     13369376);
                 mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);
                 memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
      }
                 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender,  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
      {
                 e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
      }
                   private void printButton_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
                 CaptureScreen();
                 printDocument1.Print();
      }private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);


        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;            
    }
```

I have tried some other examples and doesn't seem to improve the quality.
Any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: Are you trying to send a screencapture to the printer? For high quality you need to create the graphics in a printer quality resolution, so you should create those bar graphics in an appropriate resolution instead of copying the screen output.

Comment: I got the barcode image working, but the labels that i use for displaying the No_Producto and name dont look sharp, any help with that thx?, i have redrawn the label like this     "e.Graphics.DrawString(Namelbl.Text, drawFont, drawBrush, Namelbl.Location.X, Namelbl.Location.Y);"